# Do we need an EVENTS tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

I was going to ask a question about graduation and I didn't find the tag I was looking for. I was thinking that an "events" tag would be useful for questions about different events that academics go to (e.g., graduation, new student invocation, thesis defenses, fund raising).

**EDIT** In response to aeismail's answer, I am thinking of questions more from the faculty side of these events and not the student side, although student side questions would also work. For example a question about etiquette when walking in the graduation procession as a member of faculty.

What do people think about an EVENTS tag with a description of

> about what can be expected of and by attendees at different academic
>   events including graduation, thesis defenses, and tenure review
>   meetings.

Answer (score 6):

**No.** Looks like no action has been taken on this in 9 years, so I'll formalize it with an answer. We already have tags for `graduation`, `defense`, and `workshop`, so it's hard to see what value a catch-all tag like this would add.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "milestones" is a more appropriate tag than "events?" It's a better descriptor, at any rate. "Events" could imply conferences and other items, like seminars or training workshops.

Comment: I am coming at these events from the other side. For example, the question I was thinking about is related to walking in the graduation procession as a member of staff and not as a student. For this type of question graduation is not a milestone, but rather an event that I have to attend. Questions about training workshop etiquette (e.g., dress code, use of phones, emailing) could fall under this tag.

Comment: Fair enough. Wasn't clear from the original context. Perhaps we need both tags at some point. . . .

Comment: "rites-of-passage"?